# Hello world program in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have zero knowledge, but I can't find a hello world program for using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) to read a database table. How do I write a hello world and working program?

Comment: This site is really for questions about specific problems. If you've tried something and you're stuck, show us what you've tried and what the problem seems to be. This isn't a tutorial or 'please write my code for me' site, however. Perhaps you should search for some tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend that you check out Scott Guthrie's blog articles about [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29):

*[Using LINQ to SQL (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)*

Answer (score 3):

ScottGu wrote a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) about LINQ to SQL that you might like to read.

Answer (score 0):

Download and use LinqPad. Self-explanatory and self-sufficient learning device.

[Download here>>>](http://www.linqpad.net/)

You will not have one but a LOT of working examples.